# Nuclear Binding Energy Graph

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, binding-energy

I know it is a silly question to ask, but I am confused with the following concept. Can anyone please clear it?

As we know, the binding energy of H-1 is zero, so the fusion process would start from deuterium and end with Iron-56. On the other hand, the fission process would start from Cf-252 and end with Iron-56.

If my concept is correct, what would be the end product of the these processes in the binding curve?

Answer (score 0):

The binding energy ber nucleon curve can help you see which processes release energy.  For example if two Hydrogen atoms fuse to make Helium, since the end product (Helium) is higher up, energy is released.  The same with fission of e.g. Uranium.

Elements that have high B.E. per nucleon are more stable, you might notice that Helium is up on a little spike, higher than the surrounding elements, Helium is stable.

The highest are in the region around iron, these elements are stable, no energy would be released if it were possible to do fusion of them - and more energy is needed than for other elements to split them up.

In practice fusion can only occur with the few lightest elements and fission with a few of the heaviest.

Here is a diagram of B.E. per nucleon

https://www.miniphysics.com/binding-energy-per-nucleon-and-nuclear.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This means the Hydrogen-1(which has zero binding energy) undergoes to the fusion reaction and the fusion reaction ends at a point before the Iron-56?